# Connect SSH in UTS namespace (host-name namespace) in Ubuntu VM from host Windows

Tags: sshd, namespace

I've an assignment for school to research about namespaces.
For all of them I've made examples but UTS is not simple to demonstrate.
I've read UTS namespace is often used in *vservers* for admin purposes (naming machines in a local network) and I'd like to show so by having 2 SSH servers in 2 different UTS namespaces and showing that connection is established by 'ssh user@hostnameinns1' and 'ssh user@hostnameinns2'.
An ssh server is run at system startup while in a terminal I'm doing:

```
$ sudo unshare -u
$ hostname hostnameinns2
$ service sshd start
```

My actual set up is an Ubuntu VM inside Windows with port 22 forwarding and network in 'bridged mode'. I'm connecting from Windows but unfortunately it only connects to the first ns (the original/system one) but not to the unshared one:

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname hostnameinns2: No such host is known.`

Also, doing `$ service sshd stop` in the first ns before starting it in the second one doesn't help.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Name spaces are mainly internal to the OS. You may be able to assign 2 IPs to the  OS. Then associate one name-space to each. Also how did the MS-Windows know the name of the first? You need to ensure that the external OS (your MS-Windows) knows the name of each IP.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this with SSH you would need (at a minimum) to spawn a UTS and network namespace (or running the second copy of SSH on a different port).

For the UTS case, there is an example in the `setns` syscall man page (`man 2 setns` - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html#EXAMPLE) as well as the man page for the command you used, `unshare` (`man 1 unshare` - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html#EXAMPLES).

As per the `unshare` man page:

```
# touch /root/uts-ns
# unshare --uts=/root/uts-ns hostname FOO
# nsenter --uts=/root/uts-ns hostname
FOO
# umount /root/uts-ns
```

> Establish  a persistent UTS namespace, and modify the hostname.  The namespace is then entered with nsenter.  The namespace is destroyed by unmounting the bind reference.